# Cisco Jabber for Linux?

Tags: linux, ldap, open-source, phone

Some people at our company are using a so called `Cisco Jabber` in Windows OS to improve handling of phone calls directly at the PC instead of using the telephone anymore.

[image: Screenshot of the used Cisco Jabber]

---

After installation, one has to register the client to the server just with a `username@company.com` and the corresponding `password`. Subsequently it is possible to search for names and numbers within the client (probably `LDAP`-request) and handle incoming and outgoing calls without using the hardware telephone keyboard anymore.

**Is there some alternative available that works on Linux systems?**

Comment: If the server is a standard SIP server, then there would be for example twinkle or ekiga. If it's using proprietary cisco features, then you have to ask cisco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the original Cisco Jabber win32 instalation with winehq 5.18

Works for audio and chat, no with video.

Comment: So can you manage your landline phone calls with this variant as well?

Comment: Yes, i am testing now and it works

Comment: @antonio-j-ortiz Which version of the Cisco Jabber do you use? With some 12.x I can install it as 64-Bit in Wine, but I don't get sound... :-( If I install it as 32 Bit, even Wine does not output sound.

Comment: Ah, when installing the package "lib32-mpg123" I will get sound in WIne and in Jabber. :-)

Answer (score 3):

There are many, many XMPP chat clients for Linux such as (in no particular order):

[jabberd2](https://jabberd2.org/)

[MongooseIM](https://mongooseim.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

[Pidgin](https://pidgin.im/)

[tkabber](http://tkabber.jabber.ru/)

Answer (score 3):

Actually there is a web browser based solution that handles chat, presence and calling for Cisco UCM named [Fimbur](https://bulpros.tech/digital-workspace/business-applications/fimbur/).

It supports Linux as well.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try my [Jabber4Linux](https://github.com/schorschii/jabber4linux) for softphone functionality with the Cisco CUCM.